# Silex app->redirect does not match routes

Tags: php, redirect, silex

Let my application run on localhost, the path is: `localhost/silex/web/index.php`, defined routes as in the code below, I'd expect visiting `localhost/silex/web/index.php/redirect` *redirects* me to `localhost/silex/web/index.php/foo` and displays 'foo'. Instead it redirects me to `localhost/foo`.

I am new to Silex and maybe I got it all wrong. Could someone explain where is the problem? Is it correct behavior and it should redirect for absolute paths? Thanks.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get('/foo', function() {
    return new Response('foo');
});

$app->get('/redirect', function() use ($app) {
    return $app->redirect('/foo');
});


$app->run();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `redirect` url expects an url to redirect to, not an in-app route. Try it this way:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());

$app->get('/foo', function() {
    return new Response('foo');
})->bind("foo"); // this is the route name

$app->get('/redirect', function() use ($app) {
    return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("foo"));
});
```

Comment: Tank you for explanation, will use this! :)

Comment: Is it possible to redirect from a POST request to a GET one?

Comment: Yes, in fact if you redirect, the next request will be GET, the http spec defines this.

Answer (score 4):

For internal redirects, which does not change the requested URL, you can also use a sub-request:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$app->get('/redirect', function() use ($app) {
   $subRequest = Request::create('/foo');
   return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);
});
```

See also [Making sub-Requests](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html).

Comment: I am aware of the sub request, I just thought I can do it this way to.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Up to `"silex/silex": ">= 2.0"`, a native trait allow you to generate an URL based on the route name.

You can replace :

```
$app['url_generator']->generate('my-route-name');
```

By :

```
$app->path('my-route-name');
```

Then use it to redirect :

```
$app->redirect($app->path('my-route-name'));
```

Another possibility is to create a custom trait to directly redirect with a route name :

```
namespace Acme;

trait RedirectToRouteTrait
{
    public function redirectToRoute($routeName, $parameters = [], $status = 302, $headers = [])
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->path($routeName, $parameters), $status, $headers);
    }
}
```

Add the trait to your application definition :

```
use Silex\Application as BaseApplication;

class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    use Acme\RedirectToRouteTrait;
}
```

Then use it wherever you need it :

```
$app->redirectToRoute('my-route-name');
```

Comment: Scalar type hints are available in PHP7 only. You would better remove them from your snippets.